Solving a System of Fully-Integer Linear Equations over a Bounded Finite Integer Vector Space with Clamping
Title is a bit of a mouthful, apologies.
Solving a system of integer linear equations which "describe a vector space" is a fairly well-explored problem with a number of good off-the-shelf solutions. I am pretty sure that being over the integers rather than the scalars means such problems technically deal with modules rather than vector spaces (would love to be corrected on that, though), but I'm speaking specifically about those spaces that are sufficiently well-behaved as to be generated from a set of basis vectors. Those seem to be pretty consistently referred to as "vector spaces" regardless, probably because they behave as actual vector spaces in a lot of ways.
Possible abuse of terminology aside, I have an $N$-dimensional integer vector space $V$ over $\Bbb{Z}^N$ such that each of the $N$ dimensions has a minimum value $MIN_n \in \Bbb{Z}$ and maximum value $MAX_n \in \Bbb{Z}$. We can assume that all points in that space with integer coordinates can be generated from linear combinations of a set of vectors $B$ over $\Bbb{Z}^N$, which is a set of vectors entirely within the space and we know contains at least a set of basis vectors sufficient to produce that whole space.
The goal is to start at some point $p_s \in V$ and, through the linear combination of the vectors in $B$, reach another point $p_f \in V$.
Ignoring the bounds constraint allows us to solve this as we would any other system of integer linear equations, by subtracting out the goal values to obtain $Ax=0$ which we then solve. Or, slightly less mathematically conventional but apparently more computationally conventional, obtaining and solving $Ax=p_f-p_s$.
Assuming we minimize the solution, this will give us $c_u$, the count of each of the vectors in $B$ that when summed provide the shortest path $P_su$ from $p_s$ to $p_f$ through the unbounded space. Addition being commutative, we can reorder this summation as we please so as to attempt to produce some path $P_b$ which stays within each dimension's bounds at every step. I haven't fully explored how often $P_b$ is impossible to generate from $c_u$, but it seems both relatively infrequent with the right set of vectors and relatively easy to address when it does happen by only slightly lengthening the path taken.
There is, however, one further wrinkle: the vector space in question exhibits a sort of "clamping" behavior at the bounds of each dimension. For a point $p \in V$ and a vector $\vec{b} \in B$ such that conventionally $p+\vec{b} \notin V$, we instead clamp the result of the addition along each of its dimensions that would exceed their bounds.
More generally, we define $p+\vec{b}=q$ piecewise as follows for each dimension $n$:
$$
q_n =
\begin{cases}
MAX_n & \text{if $p_n+b_n$ > $MAX_n$} \\
p_n + b_n & \text{if $p_n+b_n$ in $[MIN_n, MAX_n]$} \\
MIN_N & \text{if $p_n+b_n$ < $MIN_n$}
\end{cases}
$$
As mentioned, if we are able to accept only finding a path from $p_s$ to $p_f$ then the above assumption gives us a sufficient approach. After all, any path (minimal or otherwise) through the unbounded space that we force to "coincidentally" remain within the bounds is also by definition a path within the bounded space. It just might not be the shortest possible path through the bounded space.
I don't just yet want to give up on using this to find a potentially even shorter path by leveraging the clamping behavior, though. I'm really struggling to definitively determine one way or the other if that's even possible, but I think it should be.
Is it, though? Can this behavior even be expressed as a part of the system of integer linear equations? If it can then that would be ideal since I'd presumably be able to simply feed whatever additional equations are necessary into scipy.optimize.milp (or whichever solver works best for the use case) as part of the matrix and constraints.
The piecewise function above is both defined and linear for its entire domain, so it's still itself linear. Which should mean that it's possible to reformulate the equation and express it simultaneously with the other equations in the system, I would think. But I've yet to successfully do so in a way that preserves the solvability of the system of equations.

I would love if you can summarise it more and make it more 'mathematical'

I'm... not sure what you mean, I have to admit. The whole problem is fundamentally about using linear algebra in order to solve set theory problems, and if that's not math I don't know what is.

https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10030/linearize-constraints-on-a-truncated-variable
